# no S/PDIF audio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, spdif

I am unable to get any S/PDIF audio out of a machine running KDE on Ubuntu 16.04

The machine is dual boot, in windows the S/PDIF and HDMI audio both work fine.

In Linux S/PDIF audio does not work but HDMI audio works fine.

In pavucontrol->configuration I have enabled both built in audio (built in audio digital stereo IEC958) and HDA Nvidia (HDMI output).

In pavucontrol->playback, if I set Chrome to playback on S/PDIF in the playback tab, I can see the audio meter in pavucontrol moving but no sound is output. If I set it to HDMI playback I can see the audio meter moving and hear audio.

In alsa mixer I can see 2x S/PDIF channels and they are both enabled.

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score -2):

Without pretending that my experience is the solution, on my computer (Linux MINT 20.3) I did the following in the terminal (found on the www):

sudo apt install libavresample-dev pavucontrol libasound2-plugins-extra

Than open Pavucontrol, chose S/PDIF and under "Advanced" check all the checkboxes.

Than very important: the S/PDIF doesn't give any sound when the analog channel is below 100% volume. So first set the analog volume to 100% and return to the S/PDIF. Now on my computer I can use S/PDIF including a smooth volume control.

Comment: Hello. Do you know for sure your experience with an supported OS will work in Ubuntu?

Comment: LM is not Ubuntu. I'd appriciate if you could test the solution on Ubuntu, and report back.